# I'm getting a 500 error for my multi site network

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just installed a Wordpress installation on my WAMP stack running Apache 2.2.17, MYSQL 5.5.8 and PHP 3.3.5... It's a fresh 4.0 Beta Version.. Just the one I had on hand I'm experimenting with the Multi Site..and here is where my problem is.. I did as it said on Codex... but when i copied and pasted the new htaccess rules with the rewrite module active.. I'm getting a 500.. But I did look into my Apache error log and here is what it says `[Sat Dec 13 11:15:05 2014] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] E:/wamp/www/Multiple Site Network Sandbox/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters referer: http://localhost`, as I'm still learning I don't know what it means... here is my .htaccess file..

Lemme know!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Multiple%20Site%20Network%20Sandbox/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) E:/wamp/www/Multiple Site Network Sandbox/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ E:/wamp/www/Multiple Site Network Sandbox/$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: What happens if you replace the `%20`s with spaces?

Comment: I replaced the %20 with spaces and now its throwing a 404..

Comment: Ed, What if I removed them in the wp-sites table in the MYSQL database?

Comment: I'm not sure why they would be in there in the first place. It seems like you've added the name of your local folder ("Multiple Site Network Sandbox) to some URLs inadvertently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple problems.

First, you need to replace the `%20`s with spaces. That's causing your 500 error.

Second, you are hitting 404 errors. That is partly due to your `RewriteRule`s containing local paths, not web paths. Keep in mind that this is Apache; it wants URLs, not local paths. You need to do something like this (untested):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Multiple Site Network Sandbox/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) /$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ /$2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

You also seem to have some problems with the very fact that you are referencing `Multiple Site Network Sandbox`; I'm not sure why that is in this .htaccess file. If you can give more details about your local folder structure and sample URLs for your WP site network, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Ed.. This had no effect.. "htaccess: RewriteBase takes one argument, the base URL of the per-directory context"

Comment: I would strongly advise you to avoid using spaces in the directory name. Also, to be clear, are you anticipating that anyone would use a URL like `http://test-site-one/Multiple Site Network Sandbox/something`? Or is "Multiple Site Network Sandbox" just the folder holding the WP files? If it's the latter, then it shouldn't be mentioned in .htaccess at all. Rather, the .htaccess file should be *in* that folder.

Comment: Ed, I thank you for your time.. as I think I'm gonna try again.. Drop the database and take your advice! Multiple Site Network Sandbox was the folder holding the WP Files..I don't know what went wrong there it was the first time it ever happened to me.. I thought the multi site thing sounded neat so I tried to do it and it failed (; I shall try again and I will let you know how it works out!

Comment: Glad to help. I'd appreciate it if you accepted this answer, since we were at least able to get past the 500 error.